# Offset a repeating image texture position

Tags: texturing, uv, node-editor, texture-coordinates, vector-mapping

I am modeling a kitchen. Is there a way to offset an image that is repeating on the floor in the x-axis so that it looks more tiled?

[image: node set up]

[image: top-down view]

Comment: AFAIK the only way is to edit the UV map. PS: you don’t need the Combine XYZ node, you can just enter the values straight into the Mapping node.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, the Combine XYZ is from a different test I was doing and forgot to remove it from the screenshot. I was attempting to add Maths to the x-coordinate, but that wasn't doing anything.

Comment: I wish I had seen this post earlier. I imagine you have either found a solution, or moved on from this project, but I have a tutorial on how to do exactly what you're looking for: 
https://youtu.be/wFpcqbSmSs4
It's part 9 of an ongoing series. I hope you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

brick texture works to some extent, but not that good,the best way is to make a new texture.
[image]

Comment: Thank you! Yes, it's looking a different texture would work best.